# remove a list of words from a field of table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, text, nlp

I do have a table

```
T1
id |image| tags
1  | @1  |london
2  | @1  |sky
3  | @3  |cafe
4  | @4  |duck
```

and I have another table with only 1 field:

```
T2:
id | removeList
1  |sky
2  |duck
3  |city
```

I want to remove T2 list from the tag field in T1 and update the table

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
DELETE FROM T1
USING T2
WHERE T1.tags=T2.removeList
```